# Issue with WHERE statement in SQLite Android programme

Tags: java, android, sqlite, where-clause

I have been having trouble working out what's wrong with this section of code;

```
 public ArrayList<String> getAllReviews(String ShopName) {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>() ;
    String q2 = "SELECT REVIEW, SHOPNAME FROM REVIEWS" +
                " WHERE SHOPNAME = ?";
    String q = "SELECT REVIEW, SHOPNAME FROM REVIEWS";
    System.out.println(q2);

    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q2, new String[]{ShopName});
    System.out.println(c.getCount());

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c.getColumnNames()));
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            al.add(c.getString(0));
            System.out.println(c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1));
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
```

I want to pull reviews for my specific shop, specified by ShopName and display them on a review page, I am not getting any errors but the code will not display in my listView.  The code for the review page is below.  What have I done that is preventing my reviews from showing?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_reviews);

    ShopName = GetShopName(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println(ShopName);

    //Get instance of database adapter
    ratingDataBaseAdapter = new DataBaseAdapter(this);
    try {
        ratingDataBaseAdapter.open();
        ReviewObject = ratingDataBaseAdapter.getAllReviews(ShopName);

        System.out.println(ReviewObject.toString());

        ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ReviewObject);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvReviews);
        lv.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    } catch (SQLException f) {
        f.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see values in logs?

Comment: Values won't print in log with WHERE but when I get all of the reviews without the WHERE they print fine

Comment: Try seeing if you have entry for `ShopName` you are passing in the table. There might not be any entry in the table for the value you are passing.

Comment: Yes, There is definitely a value

Comment: What evidence do you have for that? The output of your code indicates that there is no such value.